# Pickling on GAE ndb

Tags: google-app-engine, pickle, app-engine-ndb, defaultdict

I am trying to pickle and unpickle structured data into an ndb.PickleProperty() property like so:

```
month = MonthRecord.get_or_insert(month_yr_str, parent=ndb.Key('Type','Grocery'), record=pickle.dumps(defaultdict(list_list)))
names_dict = pickle.loads(month.record) # unpickle for updating
# ...                                   # some modifications on names_dict
month.record = pickle.dumps(names_dict) # pickle
month.put()                             # commit changes
```

where the model MonthRecord is defined as:

```
class MonthRecord(ndb.Model):
    record = ndb.PickleProperty() # {name: [[date&time],[expenses]]}
```

and list_list as:

```
def list_list(): # placeholder function needed by pickle at module level
    return [[],[]]
```

The first run works fine (where insert case is hit in get_or_insert, creating a new MonthRecord entity). However, during succeeding runs (i.e. new expenses within current month to be recorded) the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\GAE_Projects\qb_lite\fin.py", line 31, in update_db
    names_dict = pickle.loads(month.record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1382, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1133, in load_reduce
    value = func(*args)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

Any ideas as to the cause of error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to pickle your objects, that will be handled by PickleProperty.

Instead of:

```
month = MonthRecord.get_or_insert(
    month_yr_str,
    parent=ndb.Key('Type','Grocery'),
    record=pickle.dumps(defaultdict(list_list)))
```

do:

```
month = MonthRecord.get_or_insert(
    month_yr_str,
    parent=ndb.Key('Type','Grocery'),
    record=defaultdict(list_list))
```

Pickling and unpickling will be taken care of internally.

Comment: Verified that whether there is an extra/redundant pickling or not, the code works. The real cause of the problem is instead the datetime objects with tzinfo, which couldn't be pickled properly as TimeZone is not defined at the module level. Fixed by removing tzinfo in the datetime objects. Root cause was uncovered when I removed the extra layer of pickling. Now using PickleProperty the proper way. Thanks.